# How do I configure wvdial to connect using a micromax 353g usb modem?

Tags: unity, usb-modem, wvdial

I have Micromax 353g usb modem . M using Ubuntu 11.04... I installed wvdail nd configured `wvdial.conf` as

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = ATS7=60 S30=0 S0=0
Init4 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"aircelgprs.pr"
Password = Aircel
Phone = *99***#  
Modem Type = USB Modem
Stupid Mode = 1
Baud = 7200000
New PPD = yes
Dial Attempts = 1
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB2
ISDN = 0
Username = aircel
```

aftr commanding wvdial it says

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
--> Sending: ATQ0
--> Re-Sending: ATZ
--> Modem not responding.
```

unable to connect plz help

Answer (score 0):

Change following lines and try

Change access point, you are using old one

`Init4 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"aircelgprs"`  or `aircelinternet`

No user id and password required

`Password =`

`Username =`

You are using wrong dialing number

`Phone = *99#` OR `*99***1#`

Change the configs and let us know the result in comment.